# Difference between definterface and defprotocol in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Other than lack of documentation, what is the difference between `definterface` and `defprotocol` in Clojure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the *Joy of Clojure*:

> The advantages of using `definterface` over `defprotocol` are restricted
>   entirely to the fact that the former allows primitive types for
>   arguments and returns. At some point in the future, the same advantage
>   will likely be extended to the interfaces generated [by protocols], so use
>   `definterface` sparingly and prefer protocols unless absolutely
>   necessary.

Answer (score 5):

My possibly incomplete understanding was `definterface` produces an interface .class that java code can implement in order to create classes suitable to pass to your Clojure functions.

Protocols are, in short, a faster and more focused way of doing dispatch than multimethods. you actually have running code in a protocol that is used by other clojure code.