# Can I hint a function's parameter type in deftype?

Tags: clojure

I attempted to do:

```
(defprotocol TestP
  (fun [this ^int i]))

(deftype Test [] TestP
  (fun [this ^int i] i))
```

However, compilation fails and says `Can't find matching method: fun`. Does that mean deftype functions may not accept type hints on parameters?

Comment: FYI. You may use `definterface` if you want statically-typed Java interfaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770282/difference-between-definterface-and-defprotocol-in-clojure

Comment: thank you very much tnoda, yours is actually the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type hint in `deftype` as the error message clearly states:

> Can't find matching method: fun, leave off hints for auto match.